# Solving a non-linear system of equations with multiple variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve an matrix equation of the form $$ X^2 + AX + B = 0 $$.
After the multiplication of the matrices and after adding the matrices we get the following non-linear system of equations:
$a^2+bc+a+c\:=\:7;$
$ab+bd+b+d=-1;$
$ac+cd-a+c=0;$
$d^2+bc-b+d=0$

I've tried factoring, tried to eliminate some of the unknowns but can't find a way to solve this system.

Can somebody help me with it ?

Comment: $$\left(a =  \dfrac{21}{10},b =  -\dfrac{3}{10},c =  \dfrac{7}{10},d =  -\dfrac{1}{10}\right),(a =  -3,b =  0,c =  1,d =  -1),(a =  2,b =  0,c =  1,d =  -1),(a =  0,b =  0,c =  7,d =  -1),\left(a =  -\dfrac{14}{5},b =  \dfrac{2}{5},c =  \dfrac{7}{5},d =  -\dfrac{1}{5}\right),(a =  0,b =  6,c =  1,d =  -1)$$

Answer (score 1):

eliminating the variables $$b,c,d$$ we get for  the following equation for $a$:
$$\left( a+3 \right)  \left( a-2 \right)  \left( 14+5\,a \right) 
 \left( -21+10\,a \right) 
=0$$
don't Forget to discuss the Special cases

Comment: The special cases?

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to eliminate those variables ?

Comment: solve the equation in which the variables are linear for a variable and eliminate with the other equations stepwise the other variables